# Elasticsearch field not showing up

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and I have added new field to index in elasticsearch. When I try to read documents in this index, I am not seeing new field which I have added sometimes and sometimes it is reading. I am trying to read thru spark job.

Could you please provide any suggestions why it is behaving like this?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: after adding the new field, did you check the mapping in ES whether that field is present there.

Comment: do you want to have the field in ALL docs including these ones existed before without it?, with ES you get what you send in the document body, could you clarify with one example?

Comment: Sunder Manoj, Thanks for the response. I was able to see that field when I query Kibana. Same query I am running through spark code and not getting the column..

Comment: Panchicore, Thanks for the response. I am not looking for the field before the change. I am only expecting this field after changing the ES for this field.